# How to iterate over a list in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm passing 4 lists of the same length and the length of the lists to my template. How do I iterate over the lists?

views.py

```
def allbooks(request):
    ID = [1,2]
    bookName = ["Python", "Java"]
    author = ["idk", "who"]
    copies = [3,7]
    return render(request, 'allbooks.html',{'ID':ID,'bookName':bookName, 'author':author, 'copies':copies,'range':range(len(ID))})
```

allbooks.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<div>
    <h3>
        List of books:
    </h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Book Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Number of copies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for x in range %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{id[x]}}</td>
                    <td>{{bookName[x]}}</td>
                    <td>{{author[x]}}</td>
                    <td>{{copies[x]}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>    
{% else %}
    <h3>You must login to continue.</h3>    
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried replacing the variable x with {% forloop.counter0 %} but to no avail. How can I fix this?

Comment: Essentially, you can't, but realy you should be looking into having an actual model

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Zip all your lists to one list of tuples:

```
 books= zip(ID, bookName, author, copies)
 return render(request, 'allbooks.html',{ "books": books} )
```

Than loop over it in templates like:

```
             {% for book in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book.0 }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.2 }} </td>
                <td>{{ book.3 }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

---

I suggest a better structure for your book info:

```
books = [

{ "id":1, "name": "Python", "author":"idk", "copies": 1},
{ "id":2, "name": "Java", "author":"idk2", "copies": 3}

]
```

than iterate through it:

```
       {% for book in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.author }} </td>
                <td>{{ book.copies }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```